# NSArrayController 'Add' function now causes saved NSTableView listed entries to temporarily lose focus

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I have a few long functioning (Core Data) apps. built on an OSX (10.13.6) machine with an older version of Xcode. I customize an arrayController 'add' method to auto-insert the current date as newObject and the second adjacent column cell picks up a focus ring and is prepared for input. All works as expected for years until I attempt to run the apps. on a newer machine running Ventura (13.6.3). Now when initiating the 'add' function all the previously saved/listed entries in the table lose focus. They are sort of greyed out. Focus is restored by clicking on each entry or scrolling through via keyboard. Note if I move the [makeFirstResponder] ref. to the bottom of the code block - all listed data retains focus when initiating 'add'. However I lose the expected focus ring appearing for the cell adjacent to the date cell. In this case the new/added entry line is entirely selected. Not what I'm looking for. Anyway - any insight on how to get my implementation to work with current versions of Mac OS as it has in the past?

```
     [mWindow makeFirstResponder:table1];
     id newObject = [BatchController newObject];
     [BatchController insertObject:newObject atArrangedObjectIndex:0];
     [newObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
     [table1 editColumn:1 row:0 withEvent:nil select:YES];
 
     [search setStringValue: @""];
     [BatchController setFilterPredicate: nil];
```

[image]

Comment: Is the table view cell-based or view-based?

Comment: Cell-based defined in IB ...

Comment: The cell-based `NSTableView` is deprecated. Is converting to view-based an option?

Comment: Thx. It's an option. I'll look into it. Table config. in the app. is pretty basic. Outside of standard string input - I need to figure out how to add a date and $$ formatters plus a check box. I guess I'll need to redo the add method code. As it stands the app. is built using Core Data + bindings. For now I compiled a version for Ventura that retains focus for the pre-existing data. I just lose the blue focus ring or what ever it's called that appears in the cell adjacent to the auto-date entry cell when initiating 'add.'

Comment: I have the same issue in my own private app. The other rows are dimmed when I start editing an empty cell. I'll do some more debugging, maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: Excellent! Works here perfectly. Thanks for taking the time explaining and providing  a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell-based `NSTableView` draws all cells in placeholder style when an empty cell is edited. Hacky workaround: subclass `NSTextFieldCell` and override private method `_effectiveContentStyleForCellInView:`. As a side effect, a placeholder string is drawn as normal content.

MyTableTextFieldCell.h:

```
@interface MyTableTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell

@end
```

MyTableTextFieldCell.m:

```
/* bugfix, cell-based NSTableView, edit empty cell -> all cells draw as placeholder */

@interface NSTextFieldCell(MyTableTextFieldCell)

- (id)_effectiveContentStyleForCellInView:(NSView *)view;

@end

@implementation MyTableTextFieldCell

- (id)_effectiveContentStyleForCellInView:(NSView *)view {
    id result = [super _effectiveContentStyleForCellInView:view];
    [result setValue:@0 forKey:@"state"];
    return result;
}
```

Change the class of all text cells in the table view in IB to this subclass.

Comment: As I said above - Excellent - Works here perfectly. Thanks for taking the time explaining and providing a solution.